# excel vba listbox filling with filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

i have a sheet "Database UI" with adres on column D

i have a sheet "Database Klant" with all the customers with there adres

i try to filter and show all rows from Database UI with the same adres on userform1

the problem is that the listbox1 stays empty no errors show
what did i wrong in the code

```
    Private Sub userform_Initialize()
    Dim RowMax As Integer
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim countExit As Integer
    Dim CellCombo2 As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database IU")
    RowMax = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    'find last row of sheet in column D

    ListBox1.Clear
    'clear all value of comboBox1

    With ListBox1
        For i = 1 To RowMax
            If wsh.Cells(i, "D").Value = str3 Then
            'Just show value of mapping with column D
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50"
        .AddItem wsh.Cells(i, "E").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = wsh.Cells(i, "F").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = wsh.Cells(i, "G").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = wsh.Cells(i, "H").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = wsh.Cells(i, "I").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = wsh.Cells(i, "J").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = wsh.Cells(i, "K").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = wsh.Cells(i, "L").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 8) = wsh.Cells(i, "M").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 9) = wsh.Cells(i, "N").Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 10) = wsh.Cells(i, "O").Value

        Else
        End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]
thanks in advance

Comment: After getting RowMax, add a line that sez  MsgBox("Count=" & Rows.Count & ",  Max=" & RowMax)   'just to see what these values are.  Maybe also add  Me.Adres.Caption

Comment: Count = 1048576 max = 5  me.adres.caption = null (edit this to str3) str3 = Kelvinring 52 after editing the listbox1 is still empty

Comment: Now, we can see that  "For i = 1 To RowMax"  only looks at the first 5 rows. Is that what you want?  RowMax looks in column D, but the comment below it sez column A.  Which is right, the code or the comment?

Comment: the code sorry before it was A didnt edit the comment yet :) first 5 rows is right because there are no more record for now test data are 5 rows but the code reads the first five rows that good but it not showing the values of that rows in de listbox then

Comment: OK, then on to the compare --  col.D vs str3 --- and str3 is set elsewhere to Kelvinring 52.  So the values in col.D are not equal to that.  There may be leading or trailing blanks in one or the other, or the number of spaces may be different or capitalization may be different.  Check again what is in col.D and what is in str3.  Add a line after "then" to debug.print col.D and col.E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some puzzling and trying and copy and pasting of pieces of code it finely works here is the working code for me now

this code in module

```
Public str2$
```

this code in

```
Private Sub userform_activate()
Klant.Caption = str2
End Sub
```

and this in

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Blad8.Activate
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim countExit As Integer
Dim CellCombo2 As String
Dim i As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database IU")
RowMax = wsh.cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
'find last row of sheet in column A

Filters.Clear
'clear all value of comboBox2

With Filters
    For i = 1 To RowMax
        If wsh.cells(i, "C").Value = str2 Then
        'Just show value of mapping with column A
        .AddItem wsh.cells(i, "N").Value
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

thanks in advance for you time and helping